# How to calculate the area of the axis aligned minimum bounding box formed out of set of points which belong to at least one of the given circles

Tags: math, data-structures, geometry, bounding-box, game-theory

I have a problem in which the aim is to calculate the area of the axis aligned minimum bounding box formed out of set of points of a circle.

I.e.

```
Array x = [x1, x2, x3]
Array y = [y1, y2, y3]
Array r = [r1, r2, r3]
```

x - x coordinates, y - y coordinated and radius

Any hint, on how to approach?

Answer (score 0):

Since the bounding box is aligned with the axes, you need concern yourself only with the leftmost, rightmost, highest, and lowest point in each circle. The leftmost point of the circle centered at (x1, y1) with radius r1 is the point (x1-r1, y1). Therefore the x-coordinate of your left points of the bounding box is, in Python code, at

```
xmin = min(x[k]-r[k] for k in range(len(x)))
```

And similarly for xmax, ymin, and ymax.

If you don't want Python generator expressions, you use another language without them, or the arrays are too large to loop over them four times, just loop once over the array indices and find the minimum of x[k]-r[k], x[k]+r[k], etc.